# How can I respec Shepard?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've imported my Shepard from Mass Effect 2, and it looks like he starts at level 30 and has skill points already spent. They seem to match the skills I had on him in Mass Effect 2.

[image]

Is there a way I can respec?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Mass Effect 3, you can respec Shepard (*or* any of your squadmates) directly from the Med Bay. Instead of Eezo, it just costs credits - the first one's free, and each one beyond that takes 5000 more credits. In my tests, it increases strictly linearly.

- 1st respec = 0 credits
- 2nd respec = 5000 credits
- 3rd respec = 10000 credits
- 4th respec = 15000 credits

The cost maxes out at 25000 credits.

The cost is separate for each squadmate.

Comment: Does the respec cost eventually cap out, or does it keep getting higher? And can you do this starting from the beginning of the game, or is it gated behind game progression, like in ME2?

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes you can do this from the start of the game. Dunno about if (when) it caps out.

Comment: Where is this Med Bay?

Comment: @Konerak On the Crew Deck

Comment: Respecing is like a street drug: the first hit is free.

Comment: @FAE Coalesced.ini lists respec costs up to 25000 on the 6th use.

Comment: @FAE, It's gated in the sense that you have to be able to get to the Med Bay first, which you can't do until after running around the Citadel after Mars.  But that's only maybe 2 hours in if you don't rush it, and only one combat mission.

Answer (score 15):

Log into your ME 2, load your last save, go to the Normandy, go to lab upgrades, retrain powers but don't put points in any skills, and save the game. Run ME3, start a new game, import the save you just made in ME2. Enjoy.

Comment: Heh. I like the creativity! But I'm wondering how to do it within ME3.