# Does the Imported Level Increase the Difficulty?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When importing a character you start at a maximum level of 30.

Does this actually make the game any easier? I understand that you will start off with lot of upgrade points, but will the enemies also scale to your level?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on how it worked in [Mass Effect 2](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/944906-/58144941) and personal experience in ME3, enemies scale to levels, regardless of how the levels were acquired.  As such, the answer to your question is yes and no.  Compared to an unimported character at the same place in the campaign, it will be more difficult, but compared to an unimported character of the same level, it should be about the same difficulty.

*Edit: Now with science!*

I played through the first 15 minutes of the campaign twice, once with my imported ME2 character and then with a brand new character.  Below is a spreadsheet with the amount of body shots I counted before the enemy died.  All shots are from the starting pistol.  Note that these are wild approximations - it's hard to count with friendlies firing as well, and I likely landed a few headshots without realizing it.  *Note: Both characters attained levels over the course of testing.  No skills were spent on either, and only the character level at the start of each area is listed*

[image: kill shots required for killing]

As hypothesized, enemies on Earth were roughly the same difficulty (it was made as a basic tutorial).  Once I reached Mars, though, the enemies seemed to take more body shots  when Shepard was at a higher level.

Comment: While I believe your answer is correct, your link goes to the combat page for Mass Effect 1. The one for Mass Effect 3 is [here](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Combat_%28Mass_Effect_3%29) and doesn't talk about it yet. But I really doubt they would have changed this from the previous two games, and if I had to fight the stuff my level 35 guy is fighting back when I was level 1, I'd be dead.

Comment: @Sterno You seem to be right.  I thought the linked wikia page was for the series with each game having specific pages.  That seems to be wrong, so I'll take the link out.  Through personal experience, though, I can attest that combat difficulty *is* scaled up for imported characters.

Comment: @DaveMcClelland I haven't tried it yet with a fresh character. But after spending 4 hours with my level 29+ I am surprised that it is scaled as the enemies seem very easy.

Comment: @row1 I played through ME2 about a month ago and imported that character.  The enemies I've fought so far (even on Earth) seemed more or less on par with the enemies I was fighting near the end of ME3.

Comment: I think we need some Science!™

Comment: @Sterno I'm a big fan of science-ing.  Do you have a proposition for a conclusive experiment to run?  I was thinking starting two games, one with my imported character and one with a new character and counting the amount of headshots needed to kill the starting enemies.  That seems hard to ensure accuracy on, though...

Comment: Grab a level 30 guy with no talent points spent and see how many pistol shots it takes him to kill an enemy on Mars. Then start a new character and do the same thing. If they take the exact same number of pistol shots, without talents, then it sounds like it doesn't scale. If the higher level guy takes significantly more, it does.

Comment: @Sterno Good plan.  I'll perform some science after work.  Is there a way to remove skill points from your ME2 character after importing?

Comment: @DaveMcClelland Not without a trip to Normandy's medical bay. But see [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53553/3062) for a way to import a Shepard with his points unspent. Also, I highly recommend using Mars for the test instead of Earth... those Earth enemies seemed to be "tutorial mode" and appeared to be unnaturally weak.

Comment: Science wins yet again.

Answer (score 1):

So i tried a little science myself, going beyond mars (if anyone is still following this) Using a save editor i tried several different missions through the campaign with a variety of different levels, what you would be with both a new game and if you were max level. they were approximations of course but the difference was clear to see.

Enemies are more than just tougher, theres more waves of them and you even meet high level enemies much sooner, for instance playing the female krogan mission on level 10 had you fight regular cerberus dudes, the guys with shields and then the guys with the extra shield healthbar. same mission on level 37 i encountered nemesis'(the sniper bitches) and a lot more engineers and shield guys. In fact the regular grunts were less common in favor of the specialists that had sheilds to stop you spamming biotics.

So TL;DR it definitely scales, and scales more than just how much damage enemies can take.