# Do enemies scale?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Since one may import a character from ME2, this led me to think that if one starts with a fresh character, the enemies are most likely 'scaled down' to your level.

Is this correct?  Are there other instances of enemy scaling in ME3?  Is it quite extreme (like it was in Oblivion for example, where suddenly everything was daedric), or does it feel natural?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the Imported Level Increase the Difficulty?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53594/does-the-imported-level-increase-the-difficulty) The question title is different, but the meat of the question is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, enemies have scaled with level [since Mass Effect 1](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Combat#Combat_Difficulty) and Mass Effect 3 appears to be no exception from my experience.

Since an imported level 30 character [experiences a normal difficulty in the start of the game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53833/11920) rather than being totally overpowered I think it's quite apparent that **difficulty does scale with level**. If enemies didn't scale with level, imported characters would be *totally broken* so it's easy to see why they kept the scaling difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience so far, yes, they do scale.  My Shepard started out in the 20's, and the early enemies were still able to deal significant damage and took multiple shots to take down.  I can only imagine if someone was level 1 going through this section with the same level of difficulty in the enemies, that they'd be ripped apart.

It's not extreme, though, and I'd like to say that there's a curve to it - the enemies I'm seeing post-Mars are slightly more challenging than the ones I saw previously, even though I've not leveled considerably in the interim.