# Do I get more points with an imported character in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I imported my Mass Effect 2 character into Mass Effect 3.  She started at level 24 or something.

Immediately, I had a ton of points to put into various abilities. I wanted to play around with the high level stuff, so I threw a bunch of points into 2 abilities. I figured I would spread out future points and even out later.

However, I've gained a few levels now and haven't actually gotten any points.  This is throwing me off a bit, as my barrier is really under what it should be and I kinda want to improve my freeze ammo.

Can I expect to get more points later?  Or do I need to start over if I want to redistribute my points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you don't accidentally have auto-level turned on?

[You should be gaining 2 points per level up through level 30, and 4 points per level thereafter.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53552/336)

Alternatively, you can [respec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53574/336).

Comment: Dangit, Auto-Level was on.  It must have switched on when I tried out Story Mode (just to see how it worked).  Good to know that I can respec, thanks!