# Is it always free to respec?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've just got my first opportunity to walk around the Normandy and have spotted a *Reassign Powers* function in the med-bay that lets me respec a character for free.

Since this looks like the normal shop interface I'm wonderinf if this is *always* free?

Comment: Hmm, this is actually probably adequately covered by [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53534/how-can-i-respec-shepard).

Comment: Ah yeah. I'd missed that; the perils of a quick ask while alt-tabbed I guess. But still, same answer != same question, so the tick is yours anyway in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first time. Each subsequent time costs credits, as [Raven Dreamer explains](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53574/4076):

> - 1st respec = 0 credits
> - 2nd respec = 5000 credits
> - 3rd respec = 10000 credits
> - 4th respec = 15000 credits

In my case, my second respec was only listed as costing 4750 credits. Based on this, it would seem that the respec price may be impacted by the vendor discounts you can receive after finding intel that can be used for upgrades (accessible at the terminal in Liara's room).